# How do I open a alertcontroller from a button in tableview cell in ios 9?

Tags: uitableview, swift2, ios9, cell, uialertcontroller

I want to open an Alertview with Call button and cancel button from button in a tableview cell.

```
var arrayOfUsernames: [PFObject] = [ ]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfUsers.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Tutors"
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: CustomTableViewCell = TutorTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tutor") as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.CUsername.text = self.arrayOfUsers[indexPath.row]
    cell.Classes.text = self.arrayOfClasses[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

here is the customtableviewcell

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var CUsername: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Distance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Classes: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Rating: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func bookNow(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since UITableViewCell is a UIView subclass, and not UIViewController, you'll need to create a variable that holds a viewController you can present from.

First, you want to add a `weak` viewController var to your `CustomTableViewCell`. I recommend using a `navigationController` simply because you can use that to `pushViewController:` if you need it for other things, and you can control the stack from it if you need. If not, you can just use the UITableViewController.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, simply set the `navigationController` variable in your cell class to the current navigationController or the tableViewController:

`cell.navigationController = self.navigationController`
or...
`cell.viewController = self`

Once you do that, in your `bookNow:` method, you can now use a UIViewController to present the view. Here's what the code looks like...

Your UITableViewController class:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) → UITableViewCell? {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tutor") as! CustomTableViewCell
  // setup your cell here
  cell.navigationController = self.navigationController
  // cell.viewController = self
  return cell
}
```

In your CustomCellClass:

```
weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
// weak var viewController: UIViewController?

@IBAction func bookNow(sender: AnyObject) {
  let alertController = UIAlertController(/* setup */)
  // setup alertController
  self.navigationController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
  // self.viewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

On a side note, I strongly advice changing your variable names to lower cases. Upper cases are usually used for `Class` names

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<scholarly.CustomTableViewCell 0x7f9c8281f400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bookNow.'
this is the error i got^

Comment: when i used the navigationcontroller way u told me

Comment: Never mind thank you so much it worked i had a segue issue

Comment: if that worked you should have accepted it as Answer

Answer (score 1):

The way @meteochu suggested will work, however I prefer the protocol-delegate pattern.

Having in mind that the button is in a tableView cell, you can use a delegate so that your `ViewController` does the presenting of the Alert. Here is the protocol in your `CustomtableViewCell`:

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate: class {
   func customTableViewCell(customTableViewCell: cell, didTapButton button: UIButton)
}
```

Then add a property `weak var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?` in your `CustomTableViewCell`.

After that, again in your `CustomTableViewCell`, in your `bookNow` action, you fire the delegate like this:

```
self.delegate.customTableViewCell(self, didTapButton: sender as! UIButton) // Or just 'sender', if you set your action type to UIButton
```

Lastly, in your ViewController, where your tableView is, make sure you subscribe to the delegate of your `CustomTableViewCell` by implementing its protocol:

```
// Note the CustomTableViewCellDelegate here
class ViewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   // ...
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell: CustomTableViewCell = TutorTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tutor") as! CustomTableViewCell
      // ...
      cell.delegate = self
      return cell
   }

   // Implementing the protocol function
   func customTableViewCell(customTableViewCell: cell, didTapButton button: UIButton) {

      let phone = "+888888888888" // Sample phone number

      // Alert code
      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Call \(phone)", message:
        "Are you sure you want to perform this call?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

      // Call Button
      alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .Destructive) { action in
      // Code for making a call
      if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phone)") {
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
      } else
      })

      alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))  // Cancel button
      self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)  // Show the alert on the screen, here the ViewController does the presenting
   }
}
```

As you can see, in order to create an alert you need to use `UIAlertController`, calling it with a style of `UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert` a proper title and message.

Then you just add actions (buttons) with `.addAction` and type the code you want executed in their completion handlers. Lastly, you need to remember to present your alert with `presentViewController`.

If your number changes, the protocol has a reference to the cell that you can use to pass vie cell properties.

See more on the official documentation of [UIAlertViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) class.

Comment: when i inherit the uialertcontroller from tableviewcell there are multiple inheritance issues

Comment: Thanks for half of it and the other part the other person answered

Comment: There is no registered handler for URL scheme tel? how do i register a url scheme for this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect what @meteochu said